# Excluding gradle Child Dependecy

Tags: java, azure, gradle

I need to use org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:3.1.4 version.

```
compile group: 'org.codehaus.woodstox', name: 'stax2-api', version: '3.1.4'
```

But I need to remove it from other dependencies.

```
compile ("com.azure:azure-storage-blob:12.13.0") {
    exclude group: 'org.codehaus.woodstox', module: 'stax2-api'
}
```

When I use 'gradle -q dependencies' command, I have this result.

```
+--- com.azure:azure-storage-blob:12.13.0
|    +--- com.azure:azure-core:1.17.0 -> 1.20.0
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.12.4 -> 2.11.4
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.4 -> 2.10.0
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.4 -> 2.11.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.12.4 -> 2.11.4 (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.12.4 -> 2.10.0
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.0
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.0 -> 2.11.4
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.0 -> 2.11.4 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.10.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.0 -> 2.11.4
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.0 -> 2.11.4 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1
|    |    |    +--- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:4.2 -> 3.1.4
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:6.0.1
|    |    |         \--- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:4.2 -> 3.1.4
```

How can I resolve this? I need to remove from azure-storage-blob.

Comment: Try `exclude group: 'org.codehaus.woodstox' module: 'stax2-api'`. First: the version number is unnecessary here, second the string you gave is not the module, it's the full identifier of the dependency.

Comment: did not work :(